# Safari web extension - background script - sessionStorage and localStorage not accessible

Tags: safari, safari-web-extension

I converted an extension from Chrome to Safari using:

```
xcrun safari-web-extension-converter
```

All works except for one thing: when trying to access the localStorage or sessionStorage from background script I get:

```
SecurityError: the operation is insecure.
```

It works in all other browsers (chrome, firefox, edge) - but not here. I hope that the solution is to turn on some flag in the xcode build settings and not to try and implement some native swift code - which I (and many other developers) will not do.

Any solution?

Comment: Update: Still no answer from Apple, but a workaround is to use chrome.storage instead of window.localStorage

Comment: I've the sane problem too.